# Can BFG repo cleaner perform arbitrary operations on files?

Tags: git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

I want to squash images using tools like imageoptim-cli on MacOS from git history to shrink repo size. Can BFG support running some more arbitrary commands? My `git filter-branch` looked something like this: https://gist.github.com/zbeekman/7482ccd0e87f495387951bd612dc390e

`git filter-branch --prune-empty --tree-filter 'pwd ; ls -a ; imageoptim -a -q --verbose -d <path/to/img/dir/here> || true' -- --all`

But this ran the image tools on those files every commit, even after they had been introduced.

Answer (score 1):

BFG doesn't currently support running arbitrary commands on commits, trees or blobs it encounters.  There are a couple of PRs and issues that request  this, notably [#169](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/pull/169) and [#165](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/165), so you may be able to fashion something from those efforts, or collaborate there.